# Can connect to external networks in docker compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

here are two docker-compose.yml, one is mysql, it will create a mysql_default network

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: hki_mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Abcd1234
      - MYSQL_USER=tester
      - MYSQL_PASS=Abcd1234
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="yes"
    networks:
        default:
            ipv4_address: 172.18.0.100
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
```

another are nginx, and php , i want to connect these services to mysql_default network,

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: hki_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf    
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./src:/var/www
    links:
      - php74
      - php810
    depends_on:
      - php74
      - php810
  php74:
    container_name: web_php_74
    image: webmaketech/php74
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php74/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php74/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
  php810:
    container_name: web_php_810
    image: webmaketech/php810
    #build: ./php810
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php810/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php810/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
networks:
  default:
    name: mysql_default
    external: true
```

error:

```
hki_nginx | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
hki_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
hki_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
hki_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
hki_nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
hki_nginx | 2023/07/31 06:33:10 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "php810" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:36
hki_nginx | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php810" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:36
hki_nginx exited with code 1
```

seems like i can't connect to mysql_default, i used to these two files to build my own docker stack, but i can't use this now, because of version changed??

anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: it seems i'm using aarch64 , but the image is x86_64